# Query to Group by multiple table data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables containing data as below and I want to group data into single output.

```
table1
pid   val
1     1
2     2
```

```
table2
id   pid  val
1     1    1
2     1    2
3     2    1
```

```
table3
id   pid  val
1     1    1
2     1    2
3     2    1
4     2    1
```

Required Output:

```
 
pid    output
 1       1     (table1 val + table2 Sum(val) - table3 Sum(val))
 2       1     (table1 val + table2 Sum(val) - table3 Sum(val))
```

Please help with optimal query which can achieve this without any temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that `pid` is primary key of table1, you could use this

```
SELECT 
    t1.pid,
    t1.val + t2.sumval - t3.sumval
FROM
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        pid, SUM(val) as sumval
    FROM 
        table2
    GROUP BY 
        pid) t2
ON 
    t2.pid = t1.pid
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        pid, SUM(val) as sumval
    FROM 
        table3
    GROUP BY 
        pid) t3
ON 
    t3.pid = t1.pid;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine for me too and time taken is also adequate for large data set.